# How can i add a shape argument in a panda print function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare the shape of the following line of code before and after the dropna() function. However, i do not know how to add the shape argument in the second print function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('https://codefinity-content-media.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/10db3746-c8ff-4c55-9ac3-4affa0b65c16/titanic.csv')

print('Before dropping NaNs:', data.shape)
# drop nans here
print('After dropping NaNs:', data.dropna(inplace=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print('After dropping NaNs:', data.dropna().shape)`

or

```
data.dropna(inplace=True)
print('After dropping NaNs:', data.shape)
```